# stress test for Android apps

Tags: android, testing

I am looking for some kind of simulation mode to test my app under "real" conditions like incoming calls, user leaves it goes to other apps - various "things" happen meanwhile - user comes back, memory shortages, orientation changes, configuration changes etc..

Is there any structured test procedure for this? Is it at all possible to do this in simulation mode?
Would be great if one could just leave a test running for hours and see if the app is robust enough...

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Monkey](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkey.html) simulates user input and logs any exceptions or ANRs that result.